# Why are the methods up and down not being created with my subclass of ActiveRecord::Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading Rails 3 in Action and following the commands verbatim. However, when I run the commands

```
rails new things_i_bought
cd things_i_bought
bundle install
rails generate scaffold purchase name:string cost:float
```

The book says I should get this code:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
          def self.up #not created in my code
            create_table :purchases do |t|
              t.string :name
              t.float :cost
              t.timestamps
            end
end
          def self.down # not created in my code
            drop_table :purchases
end
 end
```

I get this code instead:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :cost

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Why are the class methods up and down not being created for me? I'm using 
rails 3.1.1 and ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

thanks for reading my book!

As JacobM and dbalatero have already explained, this is a new feature in Rails 3.1. This particular feature was added by Aaron Patterson as a way to simplify the migration syntax. In earlier versions of Rails, you would have to do as the book shows:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :purchases do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :cost
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :purchases
  end
end
```

But that's kind of repeating yourself. Aaron created a migration syntax that looks good and is simpler, calling only the methods necessary for migrating forward, but also allowing the migrations backwards (known as a "rollback") too. The same migration written with the Rails 3.1 syntax is this:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :cost
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So when this migration runs "forwards", Rails will create the purchases table with the fields. When you roll it back (or run it "backwards") then Rails will know to drop the table.

This syntax isn't entirely perfect however, and you'll run into problems with methods such as `change_column`. When that happens, it's best to stick with defining both the `def up` and `def down` methods in the migrations:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :purchases, :cost, :integer
  end

  def down
    change_column :purchases, :cost, :float 
  end
end
```

That's because in this example Rails won't know how to switch it back to the previous type. I hope this explains it better!

Comment: Man this site is awesome.  Ask a question, and within 15 minutes get an answer from *the author of the book* you asked about. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a [new feature in Rails 3.1](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/05/06/reversible-migrations/index.html).  For changes that Rails can figure out how to reverse, such as creating a table, you simply create a "change" method with the code that would have gone in "up", and it figures out how to do "down" on it's own.

You can also define "up" and "down" methods yourself -- for some changes (such as dropping a column) Rails won't be able to figure it out -- but the syntax is a bit different; it's not just `def up` instead of `def self.up` (they're now instance methods instead of class methods).

Comment: I'm running rails 3.1.1. Am I not understanding the version numbers?

Comment: The book you're reading was based on Rails 3.0 (or 3.0.1, 3.0.2, etc.).  But you're actually using Rails 3.1.1, and all of the 3.1 versions have this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the new Rails 3.1, the database migration methods are self-aware about how to run an up/down migration.

Therefore, if you define a `def change` method, it will try to use those self-aware methods: in this case, `create_table` knows to do `DROP TABLE` in a `down` context, and `CREATE TABLE` in an `up` context.

If you want the old style, you can probably keep using it and define your own `self.down` and `self.up` methods as the book describes.

Edit: here's a link to the blog post on this, called "Reversible Migrations": http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/05/06/reversible-migrations/index.html